# how to make asp:button a default button on entering text to asp:textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, defaultbutton, aspbutton

How can I set default button after text is entered into a text box. This is what I have so far. But it doesn't work

```
<td>
                    <asp:Label ID="displayrowLabel" runat="server" Text="# of Rows Displayed:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="displayRowQuery" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="displayRowButton" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="ddlPageItems_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="displayRowQuery"  ValidationExpression="[1-9][0-9]*"  ErrorMessage="Wrong Input" />
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </PagerTemplate>
```

I tried adding some jquery to handle this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("displayRowQuery").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("displayRowButton").click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set a default button for an asp:panel if you have a group of controls you need a default button for.

Basically:

```
<asp:Panel ID="aPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit2">

    <!-- Some Controls Here -->

    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="true" ID="btnSubmit2" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit2_Click" />

</asp:Panel>
```

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/defaultbutton-panel-aspnet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "#" in your id selector:

```
    $("#displayRowQuery").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#displayRowButton").click();
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** As @Nicolás has pointed out, you may have to substitute the id selectors with `ClientId` like this:

```
$("#displayRowQuery") => $("#<% = displayRowQuery.ClientId %>") 
$("#displayRowButton") >= $("#<% = displayRowButton.ClientId %>")
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to add an answe because this is fair enought.
however you may need to add some trick to convert the server-side ID to client-side id ... 

`$("#displayRowQuery") => $("#<% = displayRowQuery.ClientId %>")`
<br>
`$("#displayRowButton") >= $("#<% = displayRowButton.ClientId %>")`

Comment: Where do I add this code? I have a search page with one textbox and one submit button. I add this code and it works fine..........

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Page.Form.DefaultButton = submitQuery.UniqueID;
        Page.Form.DefaultFocus = searchQuery.ClientID;
    } ...............
I tried doing the same for displayRow..and it didn't work out.